# The difference between reduce and decrease in iterator

Tags: c++, c++11

Code like:

```
list<const char *> lst_city = {"NewYork", "Tokoyo", "ShenZhen"};
vector<string> vs_city;
vs_city.assign(lst_city.cbegin(), --lst_city.cend());
```

This is right.But if i do like this ,will be wrong:

```
vs_city.assign(lst_city.cbegin(), lst_city.cend() - 1);
```

What's the difference  -- and - 1,i am not very clear.
If it was a vector, it will be good too.So it was just because the bilateral of the list?

Comment: Same difference as with integers.

Comment: Because non random access iterators don't allow random access.

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector`'s iterators are [Random Access Iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) -- they can be shifted by an arbitrary offset with `+` and `-`, and `1` is just a particular offset.

`std::list`'s iterators can't do that: they're only [Bidirectional Iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BidirectionalIterator), which can only be incremented (`++`) and decremented (`--`) one element at a time.

You can write code that shifts an arbitrary iterator, using either of theses methods depending on the iterator's capabilities, with [`std::advance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance).

In your situation, that is, the very common shift by a single element, you can use [`std::prev`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev) and [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next).

Answer (score 0):

A linked list cannot jump to an arbitrary element in constant time. To find an element at an index, you have to follow the links between nodes one by one.

Because arbitrary jumping is not an O(1) operation, providing it as a primitive operation on list iterators would be misleading, and cause programmers to accidentally write very inefficient algorithms. Thus the operation `it - n` does not exist.

The compiler cannot distinguish between `it - 1` and other values for n, so this operation is forbidden too. You are left with using the decrement operator.

Vector iterators, on the other hand, can jump around arbitrarily in constant time.